# ClassNotFoundException: module.MainController in window but work in linux

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I got this exception when using URLClassLoader.loadClass().

```
public BorderPane getFXML(String moduleName) throws MalformedURLException,
        ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    File fileModule = new File("modules/" + moduleName);

    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL(
            "file://" + fileModule.getAbsolutePath()) });
    Class mainController = urlClassLoader.loadClass("module.MainController");

    Constructor constructor = mainController.getConstructor(Stage.class);
    Object mainControllerObj = constructor.newInstance(primaryStage);

    Method getFXML = mainController.getMethod("getFXML");
    BorderPane root = (BorderPane) getFXML.invoke(mainControllerObj);

    return root;
}
```

It works in in Linux but when I ran in Window that threw this exception.

Comment: Why aren't you using `File#toURL()` or like the preferred: `fileModule.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL()`?

Comment: What does `fileModule.exists()` returns? You should also avoid using strings to combine paths. `new File(new File("modules"), moduleName)`

Comment: @GáborBakos oh thank you. I'm too stupid.

Comment: @Tri You are just not yet experienced in this area. ;) Though this is changing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to convert a file to an absolute URL is something like the following:

```
file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL()
```

The difference on behaviour might be because on Windows the absolute path usually contains the drive and if it is not prefixed with an additional `/`, the file might not found.

So in your case this preferably looks like this:

```
File fileModule = new File("modules/" + moduleName);
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { 
        fileModule.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL() });
```